# Material ui tooltip showing undesirable animation

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Material UI Tooltip

[image]

Whenever I hover on the `Apps Icon Library` icon, the MUI Tooltip glides  from the top of the screen which is undesirable.

I want it to appear without that animation.

the code I used

```js
<Tooltip title="Icon Library" arrow>
     <Apps />
</Tooltip>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you use the `<Tooltip>` component as a wrapper to all the desired elements.

It is recommended that you use separate `<Tooltip>` for all the elements that you desire to have too.

You can do it by adding `<Tooltip>` to all the items inside the `<Apps />`